# JavaScript src files are not loaded

Tags: javascript

Ok I'm using the most current version of Aptana Studio 3 Version: 3.4.2.201308081805
Install Directory: file:/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/

I'm doing basic html and java script in a course online,  the HTML gets shown / called just fine but no matter what I call the java script file and it end's in JS ,  I get nothing,  using safari as the browser and on another computer I used the Firefox built into Aptana I believe.

Both files are in the same path also.   I've tried this on 2 different computer's so I'm wondering if I'm missing a plugin or just do not have something setup properly.

Below are file content's ,

#### Container.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Simple Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>This is a very simple HTML page</p>
    <script src= "new_file.js"</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

#### new_file.js:

```
alert("hello world");`
```

Thats it from what I can think to post, all assistance appreciated please include exact directions in the case I'm missing a plugin and where and how to download and install this.

Comment: Are you missing quotes around the actual HTML that should be there? `Container.html = "..."`?

Comment: "java script" is two words. "JavaScript" is one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty obvious syntax error in your `<script` tag.

```
<script src= "new_file.js"</script>
```

Needs one more `>` in there.

Comment: <script> src= "new_file.js"</script> I believe this is what is being suggested ?  Although Aptana says missing semi colon

Comment: No, that's still totally wrong. Have you never read a single tutorial on this? Open virtually any website on the internet, and you can see the correct use of a `<script>` tag in the source. You should read a tutorial on JavaScript rather than trying to stumble forward by trial-and-error.

Comment: Actually what I put down originally came from an ONLINE tutorial from Lynda.com so either there wrong or your wrong, as for the rest of your reply, it definitely is out of context.

Comment: Did you try the "open any website on the internet" thing I suggested? View the source of *the page we're on right now* and you can see how `<script>` tags (and indeed, every kind of tag, because the syntax is all the same) are used.

Comment: What I posted here last night worked in Aptana on a windows 7 computer today at work.   And yes I did view source code from different sites and understand what your saying,   keep in mind I was also going by what the tutorial example files had in them also.   Thank you and the other person for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you forget about `>` char, and I recommend you to put here `type="text/javascript"`. For ex:

```
<script src="./js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```